# nth-of-type is not working inside the media queries in IE 8

Tags: javascript, css

The nth-of-type is not working inside the media queries, but working outside the media queries in the same css file in IE 8.
I am using

```
<script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/files/css3-mediaqueries.js" ></script>
```

and css:

```
.j-container:nth-of-type(1), .j-container:nth-of-type(3) {
    background-color: #eee;
}/* It is working */
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

.j-container:nth-of-type(1), .j-container:nth-of-type(3) {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}/* Not working */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {

.j-container:nth-of-type(1), .j-container:nth-of-type(3) {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}/* Not working */
@media screen and (man-width: 769px) {

.j-container:nth-of-type(1), .j-container:nth-of-type(3) {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}/* Not working */
```

Comment: `nth-of-type` isn't supported in IE8, so that's no suprise ?

Comment: @adeneo I posted the same has an answer then deleted after seeing your comment. Perhaps you should do it.

Comment: What are you using to polyfill `:nth-of-type()` support in IE8 outside of media queries? As mentioned IE8 doesn't support it natively.

Comment: See this for a reference http://caniuse.com/#search=nth-

Comment: I am trying to say. Is there any way to make IE 8 to use nth-of-type in media queries.

Comment: Not with CSS, but you could probably find something similar in javascript

Comment: I'm a bit tired to test all of this, but did you notice that your media queries aren't closed?

Answer (score 0):

IE8 doesn't support a lot of the CSS3 selectors like nth, IE8 also doesn't support media queries:

http://caniuse.com/#search=media%20queries

Also your media queries are not closed which can't help.

Your selecting the first and third of type in all your media queries so you could just use a normal class instead to change the background colour?

If you want this to work in IE8 you will need to use polyfills for both media queries and CSS3 selectors, here is a nice list for your viewing pleasure:

https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills